# First fragment remains in the background after transition

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I am currently trying to create an app having a splash screen, a login screen and a register screen.

The only way to achieve exactly what I need is through fragments. Though when I try to transition from the splash screen to the login fragment the text view which was part of the splash screen remains. The same happens after transitioning from the login fragment to the register fragment as well as from the register fragment back to the login fragment. It is important to note that there is no issue during transitioning between login and register or between register and login - except the fact that the edit text stays there.

My `MainActivity.java`

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Back button is disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

My layout for `MainActivity`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StartActivity"
    android:background="@mipmap/background">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewpagerstart"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:name="com.example.distributedsystemsui.SplashFragment">

    </fragment>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The `SplashScreen.java`

```
public class SplashFragment extends Fragment {
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash, container, false);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.f_linearsplash);
        Animation animation_fadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation((StartActivity)getActivity(), R.anim.fade_in);
        linearLayout.startAnimation(animation_fadein);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_enter_left, R.anim.slide_exit_left,
                        R.anim.slide_enter_right, R.anim.slide_exit_right);
                LoginFragment loginFragment = LoginFragment.newInstance();
                ft.replace(R.id.viewpagerstart, loginFragment);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }, 3000);
        return view;

    }
}
```

And the layout for the `SplashScreen` fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginFragment"
    android:background="@color/Tranparent"
    android:id="@+id/frame_splash">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/f_linearsplash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/f_splashlogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/f_splashtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

All my search led back to nothing.

I can only assume that either the below contained in the MainActivity.xml creates a confusion (which I tried to change but no luck):

```
android:name="com.example.distributedsystemsui.SplashFragment"
```

or that I am doing a mistake in the `SplashScreen.java` that I cannot locate, even though I tried for more than 5 hours to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot replace fragments added via the `<fragment>` tag.

Instead, you should either:

1) Switch to `FragmentContainerView`, which was added in [Fragment `1.2.0`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.2.0). It does not suffer from the same issue as the `<fragment>` tag and lets you do `replace` operations without issues:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StartActivity"
    android:background="@mipmap/background">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewpagerstart"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:name="com.example.distributedsystemsui.SplashFragment">

    </androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

2) Use a `FrameLayout` in your layout and manually add the `SplashFragment` in your activity (this is essentially what `FragmentContainerView` does for you):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StartActivity"
    android:background="@mipmap/background">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewpagerstart"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

which means you need to add the SplashFragment manually:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.viewpagerstart, new SplashFragment())
            .commit()
    }
}
```

Comment: FragmentContainerView did the job for me. I've been looking for the answer to this question for days. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to do the fragment transactions from your activity instead of doing it from your fragment. You might consider having functions in your `MainActivity` as follows.

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    }

    public void goToLoginFragment() {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_enter_left, R.anim.slide_exit_left,
                R.anim.slide_enter_right, R.anim.slide_exit_right);
        LoginFragment loginFragment = LoginFragment.newInstance();
        ft.replace(R.id.viewpagerstart, loginFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    public void goToRegisterFragment() {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_enter_left, R.anim.slide_exit_left,
                R.anim.slide_enter_right, R.anim.slide_exit_right);
        LoginFragment registerFragment = RegisterFragment.newInstance();
        ft.replace(R.id.viewpagerstart, registerFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Back button is disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And then from your `SplashFragment` call the function that is defined in your activity.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).goToLoginFragment();
    }
}, 3000);
```

I hope that solves the problem.

Comment: This did not really solved the problem, though it was useful as good practice, thanks very much (for the editing as well which made the question better)!

Comment: yap, I missed the `fragment` part. Well that was pointed out by @ianhanniballake

Comment: Indeed, thanks again for the help (not teally sure if we close the post after they are answered, is it happening?)

Comment: You should keep this post. So that other devs like us could actually see your post and can get help for their problems as well.